# Assuming this != null when implementing IComparable<T>

Tags: c#, icomparable

I have an object of type `T` which implements `IComparable<T>`.  Is it okay when implementing `bool Equals (T obj)` to ommit the check `if (ReferenceEquals(this, null)) { DoSomething() }`? Can I assume that since the function could be called `this` is already not null?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @helium: That is not always true... http://stackoverflow.com/a/3143558/347172

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can assume that if the function has been called on an object, then that object is not `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You should always assume `this != null`, because C# guarantees it.