# this == null inside .NET instance method - why is that possible?

Tags: c#, .net

I've always thought that it's impossible for `this` to be null inside instance method body. Following simple program demonstrates that it is possible. Is this some documented behaviour?

```
class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Debug.Assert(this == null);
    }
}

public static void Test()
{            
    var action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Action), null, typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Bar"));
    action();
}
```

UPDATE

I agree with the answers saying that it's how this method is documented. However, I don't really understand this behaviour. Especially because it's not how C# is designed.

> We had gotten a report from somebody (likely one of the .NET groups
>   using C# (thought it wasn't yet named C# at that time)) who had
>   written code that called a method on a null pointer, but they didn’t
>   get an exception because the method didn’t access any fields (ie
>   “this” was null, but nothing in the method used it). That method then
>   called another method which did use the this point and threw an
>   exception, and a bit of head-scratching ensued. After they figured it
>   out, they sent us a note about it.
>   We thought that being able to call a method on a null instance was a
>   bit weird. Peter Golde did some testing to see what the perf impact
>   was of always using callvirt, and it was small enough that we decided
>   to make the change.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx

Comment: See my answer for an indication that CLR was intentionally designed like this already in .NET 1.0.  The article you quote is about a different (non-delegate) situation, which would be a compiler optimization - replacing a `callvirt` by a direct call when the type of the instance can be statically determined.  Note that the reason why CLR has to throw `NullReferenceException` during `callvirt` is the need for a VMT lookup based on the `this` reference; not just a semantic desire to check the reference.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3143498/158779

Comment: IMHO, it's unfortunate that there's no standard way (perhaps via attributes) to specify that a method should be invoked with `call` rather than `callvirt`, since that would have allowed types which encapsulate values [such as `string`] to have members that can operate on default-valued storage locations.  Saying `if (someString.IsNullOrEmpty)` would be much cleaner IMHO than `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString))`.

Comment: Digressing a bit - folks who use the Unity game engine are probably familiar with `this == null` because Unity overloads the `==` operator with their own implementation, which makes it possible for `this` to be null.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because you're passing `null` into the `firstArgument` of `Delegate.CreateDelegate`

So you're calling an instance method on a null object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx

> If firstArgument is a null reference and method is an instance method,
>   the result depends on the signatures of the delegate type type and of
>   method:
>
> If the signature of type explicitly includes the hidden first
>   parameter of method, the delegate is said to represent an open
>   instance method. When the delegate is invoked, the first argument in
>   the argument list is passed to the hidden instance parameter of
>   method.
>
> If the signatures of method and type match (that is, all parameter
>   types are compatible), then the delegate is said to be closed over a
>   null reference. Invoking the delegate is like calling an instance
>   method on a null instance, which is not a particularly useful thing to
>   do.

Answer (score 12):

Sure you can call into a method if you are using the call IL instruction or the delegate approach. You will set this booby trap only off if you try to access member fields which will give you the NullReferenceException you did seek for.

try

```
 int x;
 public void Bar()
 {
        x = 1; // NullRefException
        Debug.Assert(this == null);
 }
```

The BCL does even contain explicit this == null checks to aid debugging for languages which do not use callvirt (like C#) all the time. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169035/why-does-string-equalsobject-obj-check-to-see-if-this-null/10169640#10169640) for further infos.

The String class for example has such checks. There is nothing mysterious about them except that you will not see the need for them in languages like C#.

```
// Determines whether two strings match. 
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)] 
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    //this is necessary to guard against reverse-pinvokes and
    //other callers who do not use the callvirt instruction
    if (this == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    String str = obj as String;
    if (str == null) 
        return false;

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) 
        return true;

    return EqualsHelper(this, str);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the documentation for `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` [at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3860fy3.aspx).

You're "manually" calling everything, and thus instead of passing an instance in for the `this` pointer, you're passing null.  So it can happen, but you have to try really really hard.

Comment: See the following example for a really really easy way.  http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/01/c-30-extension.html

Comment: extension methods may "look" like class methods, but they really are not.  They're just static methods that act on a class instance with some extra ease-of-use built-in.  So I wouldn't call that the same thing.

Comment: I agree with you, but the list does not stop with extension methods.  C++/CLI calls non-virtual C# methods directly, giving you exactly as smooth source code as the extension methods example, this time resulting in a genuine `this == null` on the C# side.

Comment: Like in C++, `this` is rarely `null` in well designed code but the language does not try to strictly prevent that (or it would try harder and add a check on the callee side).

Answer (score 5):

`this` is a reference, so there is no problem with its being `null` from the perspective of the type system.

You may ask why `NullReferenceException` was not thrown.  The full list of circumstances when CLR throws that exception is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx).  Your case is not listed.  Yes, it *is* a `callvirt`, but to `Delegate.Invoke` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367070/difference-between-delegate-invoke-and-delegate)) rather than to `Bar`, and so the `this` reference is actually your non-null delegate!

The behavior you see has an interesting implementational consequence for CLR.  A delegate has a `Target` property (corresponds to your `this` reference) that is quite frequently `null`, namely when the delegate is static (imagine `Bar` be static).  Now there is, naturally, a private backing field for the property, called `_target`.  Does `_target` contain a null for a static delegate?  [No it doesn't.](http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/Delegates.html)  It contains a reference to the delegate itself.  Why not null?  Because a null is a legitimate target of a delegate as your example shows and CLR does not have two flavors of a `null` pointer to distinguish the static delegate somehow.

This bit of trivium demonstrates that with delegates, null targets of instance methods are no afterthought. You may still be asking the ultimate question: but why they had to be supported?

The early CLR had an ambitious plan of becoming, among others, the platform of choice even for sworn C++ developers, a goal that was approached first with Managed C++ and then with C++/CLI.  Some too challenging language features were omitten, but there was nothing really challenging about supporting instance methods executing without an instance, which is perfectly normal in C++.  Including delegate support.

The ultimate answer therefore is: because C# and CLR are two different worlds.

[More good reading](http://blog.barrkel.com/2006/05/call-vs-callvirt-for-c-non-virtual.html) and [even better reading](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/01/c-30-extension.html) to show the design allowing null instances shows its traces even in very natural C# syntactic contexts.

Answer (score 0):

this is a readonly reference in C# classes. Accordingly and as expected this can be used like any other references (in read only mode) ...

```
this == null // readonly - possible
this = new this() // write - not possible
```