# Why would I ever want to do object.ReferenceEquals(null, this) in Equals override?

Tags: c#, .net, null, this, referenceequals

Consider the following code that I was reviewing:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    return !object.ReferenceEquals(null, this)
           && (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)
           || ((other is MyType) && this.InternalEquals((MyType)other)));
}
```

The first line in this code triggered my curiosity. Whenever `this` is null, the method should return false. Now I am pretty sure the programmer meant to write `!object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)`, to shortcut situations with `null`, but he's insistent that `this` can be null. I'm insistent that it cannot (unless someone uses direct memory manipulation). Should we leave it in?

Comment: At the same time, the order of the parameters to `ReferenceEquals` doesn't matter.  Your proposed change is no different.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Yes it can. You have to work a bit, but it's *possible* to call an instance method where `this` is null.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, the argument is that during finalization, the object can become garbage collected, but some methods may still get executed, esp. in `using` blocks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow; OK. I never knew that!

Comment: @Servy: a typo in my post, there was another line at first. Now it makes more sense, I think.

Comment: @Abel: Oh it's got nothing to do with finalization. An object *can* be finalized and even GC'd while a method is running, but not if you're going to use `this` anywhere.

Comment: @Abel In such cases you can generally assert that unexpected behavior is appropriate.  It's unreasonable for anyone to thing that a method on an already GCed object would work properly.

Comment: @JonSkeet: are you saying that I should program defensively and test for `this` being null? That can become rather awkward in about every object invocation, can it not?

Comment: @Abel No, I think he's just providing an interesting tidbit of knowledge.  What needs to be done to make `this` `null` is so convoluted and in any case I've seen, clearly intentional, such that you can effectively ignore such cases and blame the caller for breaking their own method.  So while `this` can be `null`, it is appropriate (in *almost* all cases) to pretend it can't be.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625326/this-null-inside-net-instance-method-why-is-that-possible

Comment: `!object.ReferenceEquals(null, this)` is equivalent to `true`. `true && anything` is equivalent to `anything`. It's safe to remove this condition.

Comment: @Ginosaji As the OP correctly analized, `other` needs to be checked for `null`, so the appropriate fix is to change `this` to `other` in that snippet.

Comment: @Ginosaji: the discussion is (see other comments, esp. the one by Jon Skeet whether your statement is really true. It appears not to be so always ;)

Comment: @Abel: What reason did the original programmer give for putting it in? How did they think that `this` could become `null`?

Comment: @TarkaDaal: that during finalizing/disposing, like in the destructor, it _could_ be null. Maybe this is true, I'm not certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I certainly wouldn't *normally* check `this` for nullity, it's possible, without any actual memory nastiness - just a bit of reflection:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public void CheckThisForNullity()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is this null? {0}", this == null);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("CheckThisForNullity");
        var openDelegate = (Action<Test>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
               typeof(Action<Test>), method);
        openDelegate(null);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, generate IL which uses `call` instead of `callvirt` to call an instance method on a null target. Entirely legit, just not something the C# compiler would normally do.

This has nothing to do with finalization, which is hairy in its own right but in different ways. It's possible for a finalizer to run while an instance method is executing *if the CLR can prove that you're not going to use any fields in the instance* (which I would strongly expect to include the `this` reference).

As for the code presented - nope, that looks like it's just a mistake. I would rewrite it as:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    return Equals(other as MyType);
}

public bool Equals(MyType other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Now perform the equality check
}
```

... assuming that `MyType` is a class, not a struct. Note how I'm using another *public* method with the right parameter type - I'd implement `IEquatable<MyType>` at the same time.

Comment: figured I'd point out that the actual question asked was `Should we leave it in?`, and you haven't really addressed that.

Comment: @Servy, I think Jon says that in his opening statement: he wouldn't do so. Relatively simple (nasty?) trick though, should've come up with that myself. If I'd have to guard against that, I get the same kind of code in every instance method as in every extension method: checking for nullity.

Comment: Nice to add the typical equality pattern as well, great update!

Comment: One comment, correct me if I'm wrong: I don't think the GC analyzes the code to prove that a reference isn't used anymore (in a running method). I believe that's something the *JIT* does (to help the GC's run, of course).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Have edited to "CLR" to be on the safe side :)

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't normally allow methods to be called on `null`. I think that the programmer who wrote that is either coming from a C++ background (where I think methods can be called on `null`, as long as they don't access a data member of `this`) or writing defensively for special scenarios (such as invocation by reflection, as has already been said).