# Why it is allowed to use keyword "this" with null-conditional operator (this?) in c# 6.0?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Doing refactoring, I changed a variable name in expression to "`this`", and it made the expression `this?.RaiseEvent(eventArg)`. And not only it compiled well, it didn't show me any warnings. So I am confused a little bit - is there any cases when `this` can be null in C#? If not, what is the reason for such a behavior of compiler?

Comment: Why add a special case just for `this`?

Comment: C# compiler tracks unused variables and many other things as warnings, so I would expect the same for obviously useless expressions like this one.

Comment: Looks like here is the answer [this-null-inside-net-instance-method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625326/this-null-inside-net-instance-method-why-is-that-possible)

Comment: @MikeZnaet Wow, It's something I didn't know! It explains everything. If you'll make it an answer, I will certainly accept it.

Comment: That's a problem caused by "malicious" use of reflection. It's not a condition that you would run into under normal circumstances. One could argue that they could have added checks there but those are pretty low level methods so that should be done by the programmer, not the API.

Comment: @JeffMercado, not necessarily malicious at all. C# refuses to call a method on a null instance, but it isn't a .NET rule that languages have to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this == null inside .NET instance method - why is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625326/this-null-inside-net-instance-method-why-is-that-possible)