# Is the "this" reference ever null in Java

Tags: java, null, this

What is the value of this? somewhere I read that in C# (this==null) is possible. But what about in Java? That, will the following fragment ever return `true`?

```
 if(this!=null)
 {
     return false;
 }
 else
 {
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: For those who (like me) can' grok the idea that `this` *could be* `null`, read this Q&A - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143498/why-check-this-null

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> if(this!=null)
> ```

The above always evaluates to `true`, meaning that the first branch of your `if` will always get executed, and the function always returns `false`.

Comment: @StinePike Certainly. Did someone suggest otherwise? In this answer? Your point?

Comment: @EJP .. oh at first npe wrote that it is not valid.. I didn't see that he changed the text.. So as he modified, I have deleted that comment :)

Comment: @EJP: At first the question asked about `this=!null`, to which I said the syntax was invalid. Then the `=!` got changed to `!=`, so I edited the answer to match the question. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`this` can never be `null`. Because this refers to the self instance of the object. And it is only accessed when a object is already created.

so the else block is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

"this" can never be null in Java

.....?

```
if(this!=null)
{
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` means current object which can never be null.

Answer (score 0):

Within an instance method or a constructor, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is a reference to the current object .So it never be `null`.

Comment: Never false, you mean. The test is != null.

Comment: No,@EJP  the instance.I mentioned this also now.It retruns always false.

Comment: What 'instance'? The test in the OP's code is (this!= null). This test can never  be false. 'Since it is a valid syntax' has nothing to do with it either way.

Comment: @EJP - false is true for small enough values of true :-)

Comment: It is now neither right nor wrong, just meaningless. You have failed to express yourself clearly. @StephenC *de minimis curat non lex.*. :-|

Comment: True EJP..Let me know,if you found any mistake.

Comment: Not much of an improvement. It isn't English, and it doesn't really explain anything. 'this' refers to the current object, which *is* the current context, to the extent that 'current context' means anything.

Comment: Normally I would upvote a corrected answer that I had downvoted, but it shouldn't take four edits, several of which made an already meaningless answer worse, to get to a correct answer, so I am making an exception. If you don't know the answer, or can't express it clearly, leave it to others.

Comment: sure EJP,thanks for the suggestion. English in not my native language.I tried to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"this" keyword refers to the "that" object, which you are referring to..

```
class Sample
{
  int age; 
  Sample(int age)
  {
    this.age = age;   // this.age -> the variable a in the that current instance
  }
  public void display()
  {
     System.out.println(age);  //age here is actually this.age
  }
}
public class XYZ
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Sample a,b;
   a.display();
   b.display();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think logically - that's like saying `If I don't exist...`.

The thing that currently has control of the code has to exist, otherwise the code wouldn't be running in the first place.

Comment: Don't make generalizations like that. In some languages, `this` may in some circumstances be null.