# How does overloading the equality operator == really work?

Tags: c#, null, comparison, operator-overloading, equality

I have this piece of code in `MyClass`:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs)
{
    if (lhs == null || rhs == null)
        return false;

    // Other operations to check for equality
}
```

Going by the first line in the code, I'm comparing `lhs` and `rhs` to `null`. I'm not sure but I suppose that comparison itself will invoke the overload function again. And then we het to that line again, it invokes itself and so on. Sort of an infinite recursion.
But we all know that does not take place. This implies, in my opinion, that comparing with `null` does not invoke the equality overload. So what really occurs? How does comparing with `null` work?

Comment: Side note: what if **both** `lhs` and `rhs` are `null`?

Comment: That's because with `lhs == null` not both are objects of `MyClass`

Comment: As a side note, here's an excellent example by @EricLippert about how to properly implement operator overloads: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19300732/870604

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Is that valid code? Casting `null`? That's something. Can it ever be useful, though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

I stand corrected. It *does* call the `==` operator recursively (at least in LinqPad 4.5) rather than binding to `object.==`.  There are three ways to fix this:

- Overload `Equals` instead if you really want  *value* equality semantics.
- Cast `lhs` and `rhs` to `object`
- Use `Object.ReferenceEquals` as the MSDN guidelines recommend

---

> I suppose that comparison itself will invoke the overload function again

No - `null` is not a `MyClass` so the call uses the default meaning of `==` which is reference equality.

Also note that the [guidelines for overloading `==`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147.aspx) state that it should only be overloaded for immutable types, since the expected behavior for `==` is reference equality which is what happens by default.  `Equals` implies "value equality" semantics.

Comment: Right, that's true. As an aside, can we really call `null` an `object`? Technically, `null` means nothing. But, it has a representation, I believe.

Comment: I just tested it. in VS 2015 also calls recursive. i was mistaken. thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to *D Stanley* answer. To *avoid* such kind of surprizes (`Object` operator `==` is called), use `Object.ReferenceEquals` when implementing `==`:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs)   
{
    // lhs and rhs are the same instance (both are null included)
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
      return true;
    else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
      return false;

    // From here we have different instances, none of them is null
    // Other operations to check for equality
}
```